# Is it time to end [end-to-end]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it time to burn [end-to-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/end-to-end)? It seems way too broad to me, and as of this writing it has 330 questions.

This is not a proper request: I just want to get some feedback.

Comment: I never have high hopes when JavaScript is high ranked in the related tags ...

Comment: @rene yea its an angular term but its meta.

Comment: As the tag excerpt is about the test concept (which is on-topic?), the tags protractor and testing as well as selenium make sense. Might need a clean-up for the ones with javascript and angular?

Comment: i would argue that a "concept" tag could be too broad. are there going to be experts on end to end? i dont think there would because everyones stack is different.

Comment: The title of this should be "Is it time for [end-to-end] to end?

Comment: what about end-to-end encryption?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC that should just be tagged encryption

Comment: `This is the [end-to-end]`?

Comment: `Put an end to [end-to-end]`

Answer (score 13):

At the very least, it can be safely removed from everything tagged [protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protractor), which bears the description:

> Protractor is an end to end test framework

It's similar to tagging something [facebook-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api)+[api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api). Yes, it IS an API, but that fact is completely redundant as a tag. And annoying.

That would be most of the questions. Of the few remaining, there are several that could use closure, such as [Python test "framework" for testing input files and their outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120960).

Comment: @rene I've edited the deleted post to avoid future confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like it should be up for burning:

- For a question to be end-to-end it has to be very specific about **which ends** apply. The ends of an application are specific to that application stack.
- Whenever a question would apply to 'end-to-end ', such as 'end-to-end testing', it is probably better categorized under [testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing), or equivalent context. (For example, [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) or [data-integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-integrity).)
- On its own, 'end-to-end software' doesn't make a lot of sense.

Alternatively, the definition should be changed to the [end-to-end principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle) and apply to questions around the implementation or use of such.